# More different jQuery UI Tooltips on one page

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tooltip

Using jQuery UI, how can I have more tooltips with different settings on one page?

I am using tooltips with different configuraions:

```
$(document).tooltip({
        items: "[data-tooltip]",
        content: function() {
            return $(this).data("tooltip");
        },
        show: 100,
        hide: 100
});
```

and another with much more default configuration

```
$(document).tooltip({
        show: 100,
        hide: 100
});
```

How can I have them together on one site? Calling both methods together doesnt work.

Comment: I have tooltips on links and also on input fields and they need different settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you dont want to have different tooltips on the same *element*

so just use selectors and classes to choose wich tooltip is used for wich element

```
<a class="selector">dasdasdsa</a>
<span class="selector2">dadasasdasdas</span>
```

> 

```
$(".selector" ).tooltip({
    items: "[data-tooltip]",
    content: function() {
        return $(this).data("tooltip");
    },
    show: 100,
    hide: 100
 });

$(".selector2" ).tooltip({
    show: 100,
    hide: 100
 });
```

Comment: how could I be so stupid, I forget that I was using "document" selector... thanks

Comment: sure this works, but you have to initialize the tooltips after your content changes